# What does this error mean and what do I need to do to fix it?

Tags: ssrs

Could not connect to the report server http://utmvti0176/Reports/browse/ASPIREv5Test. Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer)

===================================

Unable to connect to the remote server (System)

---

Program Location:

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.ReportingService2010.IsSSLRequired()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()
   at ReportServiceClient2010.CheckAuthenticated()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ICredentials credentials, String& authCookieName, Cookie& authCookie, EndpointType& endpointType)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ConnectionProperties& connectionProperties)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.GetCredentials(String url, CancelFlag cancelFlag, IPromptCreds promptCredentials)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportProjectDeployer.PrepareDeploy()

===================================

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 172.20.154.164:443 (System)

---

Program Location:

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Answer (score 1):

The line :-

`"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 172.20.154.164:443 "`

Gives you the key point here.

Whatever is supposed to be on 172.20.154.164 listening on port 443 is either not listening (not running or mis configured); there is something else listening on that port which doesn't understand the connection and thus blocked it; or something else has specifically blocked the connection (eg a firewall). It's possible the IP address is incorrect for the target machine.

What you need to do from here :-

Ensure that the service is running on the correct target machine; that is configured for the correct port; and that no other services are conflicting or blocking the connection.

Based on the error, physical connectivity is fine, so ping tests won't give you more information. (Active Refusal rules this out).